# !important being overridden by element without inline style

Tags: html, css

I have a most interesting dilemma at work today, and I cannot even fathom why its happening. The curiosity is just killing me.

We have a client insistent on a particular font irrespective of inline styling. I don't want a debate on !important and the way it should be used.

But I'm very curious about this situation

http://partner-dashboard.qed42.webfactional.com/partner/108/insights/homepage -: Please look at the synopsis within the accordion. And notice the font family.

```
.ui-widget {
  font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.insights-widget-container {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS",Helvetica,sans-serif !important; //I am being overriden
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

[image: Inspect Element on the synopsis in the accordion]

Can someone please tell me on how this is happening> Surely !important should override, the .ui-widget. I even increased the specificity to

```
#insights-widget-container {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS",Helvetica,sans-serif !important; //I am being overriden
}
```

No luck! Would be very interesting if someone could illuminate why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're applying it to the container.  You need to change the `font-family` on each individual item to `inherit` if you want that to work, otherwise it's going to be overridden by specificity as your `!important` only will be applied to the element in your CSS selector.

`!important` does not override children rules if they are set, only rules applied to the selector.

Imagine what CSS would look like if it worked how you expected it to.  If I set a rule like this:

```
body {
   padding: 30px!important;
}
```

Would we then expect every element that was a child of body to have a `padding: 30px!important` rule applied to it?  It'd be sheer chaos.

This might be a good link to reference for further reading: **[W3C Wiki – Inheritance and Cascade](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Inheritance_and_cascade)**

Comment: Now I don't want Simon Cowell to read that comment, and waste it on a band on X Factor. But a lovely name indeed! Can suit a fantasy team that as well.

Comment: Or a brand of see-thru underwear for old dudes - now that's just wrong

Comment: Although this answer is essentially correct, note that `font-family` is an naturally inherited property, whereas `padding` is not, so they are not really comparable. `padding` would not have been listed under the "inherited from ..." section in the developer tools.

Comment: @Alohci, you're correct, however he had already stated in the response that there was a more granular assignation of `font-family`, so there won't be any cascading inheritance there just because of the `!important` tag.  That's what I was getting at in the response; maybe that wasn't totally clear.